# Crystal reports parameter won't work

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a WHERE clause in my query which should be applied only if the boolean parameter Param1 is true/checked. Problem is it's not working. How should I put Param1 in this query?

[image: Crystal Reports Screen]

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare your parameter to something (as you said... it's a boolean).

So something like:

```
WHERE {?Param1} = 1 AND t.tot> 100
```

Comment: So you mean {?Param1} returns either 0 or 1? I tried as you said and it only works when I check the checkbox. If I don't check it gives me an empty report.

Comment: i think for crystal boolean is True or False http://flylib.com/books/en/4.229.1.34/1/